# Docker web terminal

Tags: web, docker, terminal, tty

I have a VPS running Debian 8 with Docker. I want to give my customers some kind of terminal access to there container trough the web interface.

What's the best way of implementing this? And does anyone has some kind of example.

Cheers,
Ramon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spin your own web interface easily since [Docker includes a REST based API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/). There are also plenty of existing implementations of this out there, including:

- [Universal Control Plane](https://docs.docker.com/ucp/overview/)
- [UI for Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/uifd/ui-for-docker/)
- [Docker WebUI](https://hub.docker.com/r/pottava/docker-webui/)

And various others if you search Docker Hub.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! I really like the REST API idea. Going to look after that! Now going to look for a Web terminal emulator implementation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Because you're also asking for examples: A very easy implementation for a UI is the following:

1. install the docker engine (`curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh`)
2. Start the docker daemon: (`sudo service docker start`)
3. Run the ui-for-docker container and map the port 9000:
   `docker run -d -p 9000:9000 --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock uifd/ui-for-docker`

access `server-ip:9000` in your browser.

Comment: I see this was also a proposal of BMitch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just know what is happening in your docker registry, than you also may want to try this [UI for Docker Registry](https://github.com/Evedel/bow). It is a bit "raw" now, but it has features that other have not.

- It shows dependence tree (FROM directive) of stored images.
- It shows pretty statistics about uploads number and image sizes.
- Can serve multiple repositories.